# Calculating the mean words produced by a participant in R

Tags: r, average, mean

I am working with R. I am working with a dataset and I need to calculate the average of words produced by participants within a group. My data looks like this.

```
Group   Participants   WORDS
A          John         table
A          John         chair
A          John         house
A          Steph        pool
A          Steph        backyard
A          Carlos       street
B          Pedro        stop
B          Pedro        basket 
B          Jeff         dog
B          Alan         cat
B          Alan         river
C          Steve        ocean 
C          Steve        boat
C          Steve        hammer 
C          Steve        temperature 
C          Steve        sun
C          Bryan        outlet 
C          Mark         printer
C          Kobe         basket
C          Kobe         internet 
C          Kobe         legend
C          Kobe         ball
```

So, for example... within the group A we have only three (3) participants and a total of six (6) words produced. Within that group we have an average of two (2) words produced by each participants.

My problem is that since I am not working with numbers, I don't know how to calculate this in R.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)

dft %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(participants = length(unique(Participants)), 
            words = length(unique(WORDS)), 
            mean_words = words/participants)
```

or (using only `dplyr` functions)

```r
library(dplyr)

dft %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(participants = n_distinct(Participants), 
            words = n_distinct(WORDS), 
            mean_words = words/participants)
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please provide sample data which is copy-pastable (e.g. using `dput`).

I generated some sample data as

```
set.seed(5555)
df <- data.frame(Group=sample(c("A","B","C"),100,replace=TRUE),
                 Participant= sample(letters[1:6],100,replace=TRUE), 
                 Words = sample(paste0(LETTERS,LETTERS),100,replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then you can do

```
groupStats <- lapply(split(df,df$Group), function(wordsAndParticipantsInGroup) {
  participantCount <- length(unique(wordsAndParticipantsInGroup$Participant))
  wordCount <- length(unique(wordsAndParticipantsInGroup$Words))
  meanWords <- wordCount/participantCount
  data.frame(participants=participantCount,meanWords = meanWords)
})

groupStats <- data.frame(Group=names(groupStats),do.call("rbind",groupStats))
```